# What is wrong in my attempt to rotate two orthogonal vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, conformal-geometry

Let $V=(1,0,0)$ and $W=(0,1,0)$ be two vector. Consider the following transformation:

$\pi/4$ rotation around the $z$-axis $V$ and $W$ concurrent counterclockwise, then $\pi/4$ rotating the result concurrent in direction from $y$-axis to $z$-axis (around $x$-axis) with fixed origin.

> I think the result vectors is $V^\prime=(1,1,1)$ and $W^\prime=(-1,1,1)$ up to positive rescaling. and the above transformation is angle-preserving. but $\left<V^\prime,W^\prime\right>\neq0$!!

What is wrong in my attempt?

Comment: $V'$ and $W'$ are not the one you are looking for. For example, notice that their length is $\sqrt{3}$, while $V$ and $W$ have length $1$ (length should not change if only rotations are applied).

Comment: Ok. you are right. is up to positive scaling my result true?

Comment: No, it's not, otherwise the two result vectors would not be orthogonal. Try using matrices.

Comment: I want to verify by imaging.

Comment: What do you mean by "in top direction" - rotating around x-axis?

Comment: No. Just transform one unit in direction $+z$ by fixing origin.

Comment: I think this wikipedia page may be helpful for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: It's still rather unclear what the second rotation is. Probably this is the real fault in your attempt - that you don't really have a very good idea what transformation you're performing.

Comment: If you want to know what is wrong in your attempt, _show us how you did it._ The question doesn't show what you did, it only shows your final result.

Comment: @Skyking I suppose that the second rotation is rotation around one of transformed vectors after first rotation, but which ? ... it should be stated...

Comment: @Widawensen My point is that in order to tell where the attempt go wrong we actually need to know what his attempt was. We need to know what the second mystery mapping actually is. As judging from the "clarification" it seems that he doesn't know  that very well himself. It could also be expressed as David K states it - we're not informed in what he actually did. Either the mystery mapping is no rotation or he miscalculated somewhere, but we now neither what the mystery mapping is or how the calculation was done. How are we to say what went wrong?

Comment: @skyking Yes, we can only make "educated guesses" ..

Comment: @C.F.G You have clarified what you mean by the second transformation but it seems that it's not a single operation but two separate rotations on two vectors separately... in the case these operations would be rotations by 90 degrees I suppose both your vectors would be the same, directed in z-direction, am I right?

Comment: @C.F.G However now you have changed the description substantially, now the phrase "(direction from $y$-axis to $z$-axis)" I would interpret again as a rotation around $x$-axis..

Comment: @Widawensen, I think you are right. I'm confused.

Comment: @C.F.G o.k, try to clarify as clear as it is possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting your pieces of clues together and some guesswork I reach the conclusion that the second transformation is no rotation at all. It looks like it's just about adding $e_z$ to the vector (which is a shearing transformation).

The rotation preserves orthogonality all right even if you seem to be scaling the result as well. But the second does **not**, if $v$, $w$ and $e_z$ are orthogonal:

$$\langle v+e_z, w+e_z\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle + \langle v,e_z\rangle + \langle e_z, w\rangle + \langle e_z, e_z \rangle = \langle e_z, e_z\rangle = 1$$

This explains exactly how you get your result $\langle V', W'\rangle = 1\ne 0$

Comment: @the second alternative hypothesis about meaning of this mysterious second "rotation" I put into comments under the question...

Answer (score 2):

If the only transformations you perform are rotations around the origin, leaving the origin fixed, it is impossible to transform the pair of vectors
$(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ 
into the pair of vectors $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,1,1).$

In fact, you start out with two vectors in the $x,y$ plane;
after a rotation around the $z$ axis the resulting vectors
are still in the $x,y$ plane.
Then you rotate by angle $\frac\pi4$ around the $x$ axis,
which should put the vectors in the plane $y=z.$

And indeed your two "result" vectors are  in the plane $y=z,$
which is fine. But you also allowed yourself to "rescale" the vectors.
My guess (only a guess since you steadfastly refuse to show your work)
is that you rescaled twice, once on the first rotation
to get $(1,1,0)$ and $(-1,1,0),$
and then again on the second rotation.
But on the second rotation, while you allowed yourself to "scale"
the $y$ and $z$ coordinates equally, you did not scale
the $x$ coordinate by the same amount.
Since you scaled by different amounts in different directions,
you changed the angles of some pairs of vectors,
including the pair you were trying to work with.